# DotNetNuke: Dnn cdn change for local intranet execution

Tags: c#, css, font-awesome, dotnetnuke

We are running DNN 9.1.1 on a local network without internet.

A fontawesome CSS is loaded through CDN and we cannot find where is it defined.

Like showed in the below image the CDN is a not resolved host and fontawesome is not loaded:

[image]

I search in all my web folder, in the DB and DNN github sources but I don't find anything.

How can change the URL for loading locally fontawesome CSS?

Is it definided somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing a text search for "font-awesome" inside all your skins folders: /Portals/_default/Skins/ ?

From your screenshot it looks like you're using Client Resource Management. Try disabling this, reload the site and right click > view page source on this page you posted. You should then be able to find the reference to font-awesome.

Comment: This guy knows! I would guess that it is referenced in a .CSS file in /portals/_default/skins somewhere (sub folder for each theme/skin package)

Comment: I tried your search but I don't find any CDN load of font-awesome... I try a clean installation of dnn 9.1.1 and the same failed CDN error occurs

Comment: @ChrisHammond is there a way to disable this CSS loading from code?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be added all the way at the bottom of the page below the `</form>` element. And then only when site is in `Edit` mode.

```
<!--CDF(Css|https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?cdv=75)-->
```

A bit strange because all the core files are usually contained withing the DNN site itself. And it is the only file that is loaded from `maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com`. The only other externally loaded file is an Open Sans font from `fonts.gstatic.com`

Comment: I've already fix the loading from fonts.gstatic.com, but the loading of this CSS from maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com seems to be compiled in some DLL.

Comment: Yes I think so too. It probably is somewhere in a core module. If found this: https://dotnetnuke.nl/Blog/build-bootstrap-websites-in-dnn